# How to send 1 USDT with web3.js

Tags: javascript, metamask

I am making a web3 project. Connected to the metamask wallet and got the address. Now, I want the user to send **1 USDT** on the `BEP.20` chain to my binance wallet, and I want to achieve that like this - a user clicks on the pay button, then metamask opens up and asks use to pay.

This is the code I use -

```js
ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [{
        from: accounts[0], // Got account address before this.
        to: '0x67243756d4144d6d3e132baa0660e0bc0cddf59b', // my binance wallet address
        value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'tether'), // How am I supposed make this 1 USDT?
    }],
});
```

The `value` part is confusing me. I want only 1 USDT but that i am using right now is giving 100000..... and more zeros.

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

EVM uses integer value. You should get exact number by following formula:

Value / 10^Decimal

USDT uses 6 decimal, ETH and other tokens usually uses 18 decimal.

1000000 = 1 * 10^6 = 1 USDT
1000000000000000000 wei = 1 * 10^18 = 1 ETH